# VideoView or WebView in YouTube Android App

Tags: android

Now this is a really stupid one! Forgive me on this question please but I really don't know the answer to it. My question is What have Youtube used to play videos intheir Android app? I mean is it a WebView or Just a simple VideoView? I used VideoView to play videos from the URL associated with them but it doesn't look as nice as YouTube's VideoView (or whatever it is)

And is there any other option to play videos from a URL other than using the code below? Because it just plays video in the native video player. If the red-marked portion in the image below is a VideoView, how does it look better than the normal VideoView? Or is it a WebView? Which one is a better option (in terms of UI) to play video from a URL? I'm using GingerBread and want to play mp4 or .flv videos in a VideoView or WebView (whichever is the better option, preferably like Android's YouTube app)

```
Uri data = Uri.parse(movieurl); 
intent.setDataAndType(data,"video/3gpp"); 
startActivity(intent);
```

[image]

Comment: how can you be sure that your video is of the same quality as the one you are looking at on youtube?

Comment: My question is not about the video itself. It's about VideoView or WebView. Do you know what the red-marked thing is? A VideoView or a WebView?

Comment: I would guess VideoView, but YouTube is closed source, there is no way to tell for AFAIK. But what I am saying is: your VideoView you say is showing worse quality than the VideoView in Youtube app. But it could be possible that the View itself is showing the same quality but the video you are trying to watch is less high quality than the one on youtube...

Comment: lol! What I meant to say by "not looking nice" was the VideoView itself wasn't looking nice, not the video :)